# data within the CCA function

Tags: vegan

Sorry, probably a foolish Q.

I'm using the CCA function in a fairly standard way to look at relationships between species at given sites and environmental variables for the same sites. I'm much more comfortable plotting in Python/Matplotlib. I was hoping to export the data from the CCA function. I can find the "site-species" data (in mycca.$CCA$u) but where are the vectors for the chemistry values stored by the function? I can't seem to find these data.

Cheers,
David.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you mean with "chemistry values stored by the function". I assume that with "chemistry values" you refer to constraints (explanatory variables). If you mean something else (such as respone variables), answer would be completely different. Here some alternatives with my initial assumption:

1. The original data frame of variables is not stored, but if the data are available in the working environment, the data frame of used variables can be re-constructed with `model.frame(mod)`, where `mod` is the ordination result object. This will fail if your working environment does not have the information on the original variables, as these are not stored.
2. The model matrix can be constructed with `model.matrix(mod)`. Model matrix is a numeric matrix of centred variables where factor variables are replaced with their contrasts (say, a 3-level factor will be represented by two numeric variables, known in statistics as contrasts and in ecology as "dummy variables"). The information is stored in the result object, and working environment need not have any supplementary data.
3. With `scores(mod, display = "lc")` you can extract the linear combinations of constraints, also known as ordination axes. However, these do not have the information on original constraining variables. With `coef(mod)` you can extract the regression coefficients applied to the model matrix to get the "lc" scores (but in CCA you also need to apply weights).